# Camera AutoFocus not turning off

Tags: android, android-camera

I'm using a Moto X and I want to turn off AF to then set the focus distance manually.

To this end I'm setting

```
CaptureRequest.ControlMode to auto
CaptureRequest.ControlAfMode to off
```

and then setting focus distance using

```
builder.set(captureRequest.lensFocusDistance, 1/focusDistance)
```

I'm also using as a cameraTemplate preview.

Using these settings am I right in thinking that the preview should be out of focus and not autofocus?

However the preview autofocuses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the moto x doesn't support the full camera2 api. It only supports the legacy camera api, therefore the camera2 api will run the legacy api in a sort of compatibility mode.